# Running a docker container inside another docker container?

Tags: node.js, unix, exec, docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to create a contained docker environment inside another contained docker environment and call it through NodeJS's `exec` function.

I've read through the Docker docs and as far as I can see, this is achieved by passing the `--privileged` flag when starting a container.

As I'm developing on a mac, I have [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) installed to make docker work correctly, so I'm not sure exactly how to set this `--privileged` flag.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
var st = 'docker run virtual_machine ls'

//log the statement in console (test)
console.log(st);

//execute the Docker command
child = exec(st,
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
  if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

But this is the output (error) I'm getting:

```
stdout: 
stderr: time="2015-02-15T18:27:15Z" level="fatal" msg="Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?" 

exec error: Error: Command failed: time="2015-02-15T18:27:15Z" level="fatal" msg="Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?"
```

How can I make this exec call work? Is it as simple as setting a flag? If so, how do I do this within boot2docker?

Thanks

Comment: The docker CLI is just an API client, I recommend using https://github.com/apocas/dockerode instead shelling out to it when working with docker from node.

Comment: Looking at your error, you're either running from OSX without having docker configured to the right API endpoint (/var/run/docker.sock is the default) or you're running in a container that doesn't have docker installed.

Comment: Did you want to start a whole extra Docker (including its daemon) inside that container, or contact the existing Docker daemon to start another container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
docker run --rm \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock \
  -v $(which docker):/bin/docker \
  --privileged \
  node:0.12 node my_script.js
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--privileged` flag would normally be used when you run your docker container that is running your NodeJS code above, not when starting your new container that does the `ls`. However, you shouldn't have to use `--privileged` in this case since your new container doesn't need it. You're probably just missing the docker socket bind mount when running your NodeJS container:

```
docker run --name nodeJS -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```